# Why does math/rand return the same result every time I restart my program?

Tags: string, random, go

I'm a little confused. I have a random string generator, here's the code:

```
package utils

import (
  "fmt"
  "math/rand"
)

var chars = []rune("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789")

func RandSeq(n int) string {
  b := make([]rune, n)
  for i := range b {
    b[i] = chars[rand.Intn(len(chars))]
  }
  fmt.Println(string(b))
  return string(b)
}
```

Every time I run this, it will generate a new random string, but if I restart the server the results will repeat themselves. Here are some results:

```
go run main.go
fpllngzieyoh43e0133ols6k1hh2gdny
xxvi7hvszwk1b182tvjzjpezi4hx9gvm
kir0xcta0opsb5qipjzb3h3x9kcegta5
m1zcv5drxckn42gb50anxndsckjdwgfw
5japz01zicapy9eqixuc9uehq235v48c
51wgg1gypq4s9miwn1dxkjqd614m58f0
fyy29g6ujmxbouxshy2plmkmhlnmdbfh
f7kq8u26873eql4yyp7fyilbb72nrtlc

go run main.go
fpllngzieyoh43e0133ols6k1hh2gdny
xxvi7hvszwk1b182tvjzjpezi4hx9gvm
kir0xcta0opsb5qipjzb3h3x9kcegta5
m1zcv5drxckn42gb50anxndsckjdwgfw
5japz01zicapy9eqixuc9uehq235v48c
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to [Seed](http://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Seed) the random number generator prior to  generating any random numbers.  A good value to use is the current unix timestamp:

```
import (
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
}
```

Note that you should only seed the RNG once at startup (or after forking), not before each random number generation.

Comment: I see. Since it's not in the main package, I put it in an `init` function.

Answer (score 2):

If `rand.Seed` is not set, it defaults the seed to `1`, giving you the same random number every time.

Seeding `rand` at startup with a random number like `rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())` will give you a changing result each time you run your program.

You can also create your own random var like:

```
var random = rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))

func main() {
    num := random.Intn(10)
    fmt.Println(num)
    num = random.Intn(10)
    fmt.Println(num)
}
```